# Gedmo\Tree test: SQLite fails, MySQL passes

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, symfony

In a simple test of a Category tree using SQLite, the test fails during setup with

> AppBundle\Tests\Entity\CategoryTest::testSetProductCategory()
>   Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException: An exception occurred while executing
>   'INSERT INTO category (title, lft, lvl, rgt, root, deletedAt,
>   parent_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["Hook", null,
>   null, null, null, null, null]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: category.lft

Performing the same test with a MySQL database the test succeeds. Test environment databases & schemas are created with console commands.

#### test setup:

```
public function setUp()
{
    self::bootKernel();
    $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager()
    ;
    $product = new \AppBundle\Entity\Product();
    $product->setName('foo');
    $this->em->persist($product);

    $cat = new \AppBundle\Entity\Category();
    $cat->setTitle('Hook');
    $this->em->persist($cat);

    $child = new \AppBundle\Entity\Category();
    $child->setTitle('Dry');
    $child->setParent($cat);
    $this->em->persist($child);

    $this->em->flush();
}
```

#### config_test.yml with SQLite:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: test
        connections:
            test:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                path:     %kernel.cache_dir%/test.sqlite
```

#### config_test.yml with MySQL:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        host:     localhost
        dbname:   flyby_test
        user:     root
        password: [password]
```

#### MySQL schema:

[image]

#### SQLite schema:

[image]

Comment: I know this is an obvious question, but I'm going to ask anyway. Are you absolutely sure that your left/right/level columns are marked as **NULL** in your SQLite schema? You're using the same schema generator for both MySQL and SQLite, but the error says otherwise.

Comment: @Andariel Schema graphics added above

Comment: There must be some something wrong with generating the appropriate values for the tree. Left/Right and Level, because that is a functionality that provided by Gedmo on the fly. I just tested it with MySQL Schema and there were no problems whatsoever. But seeing your Insert query in your error, you try to insert empty values to those columns. So I believe this is the reason behind your fail test. I don't have SQLite db now, so I'm sorry for not helping much.